# 'For Loop' to populate array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have never been good at developing arrays. I am trying to loop through a large set of data in a spreadsheet, store it in an array, and use it to basically perform a `VLOOKUP` function through an `If` statement. When I run the program I get:

> Run time error 9 - subscript out of range (noted where the error is below)

EDIT: when I comment out `Redim` statement I get an error on j "Type Mismatch"...The data only holds integers....

```
 Dim LoArray()
 Dim TargetWorkbook As Workbook
 Dim SourceWorkbook As Workbook
 Dim i As Long
 Dim j As Long
 Dim k As Long

 Assign the Workbook File Name along with its Path
 TargetPath = "C:\filepath.....xlsx"
 Set TargetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(TargetPath)
 Set SourceWorkbook = ThisWorkbook

 'Sets Counter in For Loop
 k = TargetWorkbook.Sheets("LRG Pivots").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row


 'error happens here
 ReDim LoArray(1 To i, 0 To 1)
 'Count Rows in LoadWTable
     For row = 6 To k
         i = i + 1
         j = Cells(row, 2) 'throws mismatch error
         LoArray(i, j) = Cells(i, j)
          Next row

 'Store Rows in Array
 ReDim Preserve LoArray(1 To i, 0 To 1)



 End Sub
```

Comment: What does 'i' equal at the time of the error?

Comment: I will equal 1 at the time of error

Comment: You should show where you declare `LoArray` and `i`.  BTW you can only use `ReDim Preserve` to change the last dimension of a multi-D array, so that line is going to throw an error also.

Comment: I added the `dim` statements

Comment: At the time of the redim, i = 0.  it has not been assigned a value so default is 0.

Comment: when I comment out `Redim` statement I get an error on j "Type Mismatch"...The data only holds integers....

Comment: `Cells(row, 2)` which workbook/sheet is this intended to read from?  As written it will refer to the Activesheet (assuming your code is contained in a regular module, not in a worksheet module)

Comment: It is not going to read from the worksheet that is in `TagetPath` it is going to to the another one